# Login to another user as admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, perforce, p4python

As a Perforce administrator, I can log in as another user without a password and perform actions:

```
p4 login joe
p4 -u joe revert //...
```

I'd like to do this in a Python script, using P4Python.  I've tried setting the `user` field per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210143/how-to-use-p4tickets-with-p4python):

```
from P4 import P4
p4 = P4()
p4.user = 'joe'
p4.connect()
p4.run_revert('//...')
```

and I've tried using something more similar to the command line syntax (per [this post](https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/keyword-arguments-p4python)):

```
p4 = P4()
p4.connect()
p4.run_login('joe')
p4.run_revert('//...', user='joe')
```

Both result in an exception:

> P4.P4Exception: [P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 revert
>   -k //..." )
>
> [Error]: 'Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.'

Is there a way I can log in as another Perforce user without a password in Python using P4Python?

Comment: `p4.password = ''`?

Comment: @PeterWood ran it with that, but same result.  `p4.password` is set to `''` by default.